# Ext JS: tpl config is ignoring html in Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm, bind

I need to use both of configs `tpl` and `html` within `panel` class but it's not let to render both configs.

How can be able to use both?

```
Ext.define('InfoCard.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'infocardvm'
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'table'
    },

    items: [{
        xtype: 'infocard',
        userCls: 'totalReCls',
        bind: {
            html: '{totalReBar}'
        }, //Can't use 'tpl' here because it doesn't have setTpl()
        glyph: 'xf015@FontAwesome',
        // tpl: 'TotalReBar' //When I'm uncomment the config, then ignores 'bind: html' 
    }]
});
```

Here is full sample [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ffn).

Question is related with [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/369262/ext-js-designing-a-base-class-and-override-it) at Software Engineering site.

Comment: The two configs can not be used together, when a tpl is present it will be used. What do you want to archive? Maybe the tpl can be modified to include the html part.

Comment: @And-y My aim is render record from backend with bind descriptior. Here only html config is able for that (It's include setter method) and also I need render a static `string` so I tried to use `tpl`.

Comment: I've added another related post notification to question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`displayfield`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.form.field.Display.html) inside of items of [`panel`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html). In display field have methods for [`setValue()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.form.field.Display.html#method-setValue) and [`setFieldLabel()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.form.field.Display.html#method-setFieldLabel). So you can change on basis of requirement.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fkb)**, I have created a demo using your code and put modification. Hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.define('InfoCard.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    tbar: [{
        text: 'Refresh data',
        handler: function () {
            var vm = this.up('panel').getViewModel(),
                store = vm.getStore('firstStore');

            store.getProxy().setUrl('stat1.json');
            store.load();
        }
    }],

    viewModel: {
        type: 'infocardvm'
    },
    layout: {
        type: 'table'
    },

    defaults: {
        xtype: 'infocard',
    },
    items: [{
        items: {
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Total ReBar',
            bind: '{totalReBar}'
        },
        glyph: 'xf015@FontAwesome'
    }, {
        items: {
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Total RoBar',
            bind: '{totalRoBar}'
        },
        bodyStyle: {
            "background-color": "#DFE684"
        },
        glyph: 'xf015@FontAwesome'
    }, {
        items: {
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Total PaBar',
            bind: '{totalPaBar}'
        },
        bodyStyle: {
            "background-color": "#fbe3ab"
        },
        glyph: 'xf015@FontAwesome'
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When I understand you correctly you want to render a static string with a variable value.

```
{
    xtype: 'infocard',
    bind: { data: '{totalReBar}' },  // bind the data for the tpl
    tpl: 'TotalReBar {totalCount}'   // use the data provided via binding in the tpl
}
```

The formula now has to return an object for the tpl data binding.
You can access the values in the tpl via the key's.

```
formulas: {
    totalReBar: {
        bind: {bindTo: '{firstStore}', deep: true},
        get: function (store) {
            var record = store.findRecord("code", "TOTALRE");
            return {
                totalCount: record ? record.get("totalcount") : "-1"  // totalCount is now available in the tpl as a variable
            };
        }
    },
```

See the [modified fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fkj).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you want is this:

```
    {
        xtype: 'infocard',
        userCls: 'totalReCls',
        bind: {data: {'myVal': '{totalReBar}'}},
        glyph: 'xf015@FontAwesome',
        tpl: '{myVal}'
    }
```

hope that helps